# how to call a joomla! module in a php page OUTSIDE joomla! directory?

Tags: joomla

i searched on the net for my answer,but the more i search,the less i find.here is the problem:

> i have a joomla! website,located in localhost/joomla.
>
> i have a php page, located in localhost/sample.php

now, how can i include some of joomla's modules,in this single "sample.php" page??

> for example, how can i use "latest news" or "latest users" in my "sample.php" page?

one of mye friend did this, but i no longer can contact him. any help would be appreciated. if the question is not clear enough,plz let me know.
tnx

Comment: Look at error.php for an exmaple

Comment: i know sir. but error.php is included in joomla'a folder. my sample.php is OUTSIDE the joomla folder.

Comment: Just change the reference to the platform location.

Comment: Generally when you have an issue and nobody else has the same problem, it may happen that you are asking the wrong question or going for the wrong approach. Even more being a "little noob" does not help either, because you don't have the general understanding on how Joomla works.

Comment: i just wanted to be polite! none of the answers on this site did not help me. I always find my answer my own. i think i made all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load the Joomla framework inside the external php file
like it says here http://www.irfanview.0fees.net/how-to-load-the-parameters-of-a-joomla-module-inside-an-external-php-file/

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to do this, but first I think you would have to load the Joomla framework (see the installations root index.php) then you would have create a session using Jsession. This is just a guess so take it for what its worth.

Comment: tnx sandra,but can you be a little more specific?don't you have any information to let me know how to do this?sry i'm a little noob at this...